# 4D Matrix from Matlab to OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, matrix, yaml

I have to export matrices from Matlab to OpenCV. I use the yaml format and then read the file in OpenCV with `cv::FileStorage modelFile`, and store the data in `cv::Mat` variables. For normal 2D Matrices, it works fine. But, for one of my big 4D Matrix, I get errors that the string is too long. The Matrix has the size of 16|16|70409|8.

Does someone know a good way to store it? Maybe it is only a format problem.

The code is:

```
for i = 1:matrixSize(1)
   for j=1:matrixSize(2) 
       fprintf( file, '    - [');   
       for a = 1:matrixSize(3)
           for b = 1:matrixSize(4)
               fprintf( file, '%.6f', A(i,j,a,b));
               if(a ~= matrixSize(3))
                fprintf( file, ',');
               end
           end
       end
       fprintf( file, ']\n');
   end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [MATLAB's OpenCV Interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/opencv-interface.html) and [mexopencv](http://kyamagu.github.io/mexopencv/). Long story short: you can use `mex`' `MxArray.toMat()` method to create `cv::Mat`.

Comment: thank you for your anwser Dev-iL . 
As I understand I need Matlab still for my applicaction?
The problem is I can't use the Matlab libraries later.
Am I right?

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand previously that you wanted to do the export once and "forget about MATLAB" after you did it. I am unfamiliar with how to best store `cv::Mat` data on the harddrive, but whichever way you choose, I think you can make the saving-to-file part of the process happen within your `mex`. This way you only run the code once in MATLAB (during export) and can later load it using OpenCV. As I am unfamiliar with the fine details of the process I'm not writing a full answer.

Comment: Yes, I have to look for more options, because at the moment I am getting also a lot of memory allocation errors when storing so much data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is to use instead of yaml, save the model in binary format and then read it with the normal fread functions. 
Of course you have to know the size of each matrices.

```
fileID = fopen(BinModel,'w');
fwrite(fileID,[size(model.nSegs),0,0],'uint32'); % size of the matrix 
fwrite(fileID,model.nSegs,'uint8'); % matrix data
```

The file shrinks from 1.4 GB to 200 MB.

Saludo